# MacTeX 2012 to 2013; NFSS system error, encoding scheme LGR

Tags: errors, mactex, input-encodings

I used MacTeX, 2012. After I had been playing the 2013 version, I get the following error messages that have never occurred in the 2012 version:

1 This NFSS system Is not set up properly.

2 For the LGR encording scheme defaults cmr / m / n do not form a valid font shape.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this error to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

it was because of missing packages

greek-fontenc
greek-inputenc
cbfonts-fd
cbfonts

When I updated very MacTeX 2013, it ran without error.

friendly greetings
Ewald Eckert